# how to validate mvc popup window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following code placed in the popup window. Basically what i am trying to achieve is to validate the required field in this case HRN. Unfortunately no validation is being displayed.  Please let me know how i can resolve this issue. Thank you

**View:**

@model HHIMS_Web_App.Models.CModel

```
        <div>

        <fieldset id="AddNew">
           
               @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateList", "Details", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmAsset" }))
               {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <div>
                    <div class="addConsumerInfo">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HRN)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HRN)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HRN)
                    </div>

                    <div class="consumerAddSmallBox">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB)
                        
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB)
               
                    </div>
            
                </div>

               
               }
            </fieldset>
    
        </div>


     <input type="button" id="btnSave" style="height:50px; width:85px; font-size:14px; background-color:#3399FF;white-space: normal" class="k-button" title="Save" value="Save"/>




<script type="text/javascript">


    $('#btnSave').click(function () {

           var dropdownlist = $("#Gender").data("kendoDropDownList").select();
         
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "@Url.Action("CreateList","Details")",
                data: {
  
                    HRN: $("#HRN").val(),
                    DOB: $("#DOB").val()
                    


                },

                 success: function () {
                   window.close()
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Model:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [DisplayName("HRN")]
    public string HRN { get; set;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try this for form validation

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#btnSave').click(function () {

           var validation = $("#frmAsset"); 
                       if (!validation.valid()) {
                         return false;
                        }
else
{

           var dropdownlist = $("#Gender").data("kendoDropDownList").select();

          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "@Url.Action("CreateList","Details")",
                data: {

                    HRN: $("#HRN").val(),
                    DOB: $("#DOB").val()



                },

                 success: function () {
                   window.close()
                }
            });
}
        });
});
```

Comment: hi i just update my code and put   `$(document).ready(function (){});`
in your script.

Comment: hi you use `kendo Control`?

Comment: hi if you use `kendo control` then try this `var validation = ("#frmAsset").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");`

Answer (score 0):

Button must be with in the form.

Try like this,

```
           @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateList", "Details", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmAsset" }))
           {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div>
                <div class="addConsumerInfo">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HRN)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HRN)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HRN)
                </div>

                <div class="consumerAddSmallBox">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB)

                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB)

                </div>

            </div>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" style="height:50px; width:85px; font-size:14px; background-       color:#3399FF;white-space: normal" class="k-button" title="Save" value="Save"/>

           }
        </fieldset>
```